# Betfair login using simple cURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication, betfair

I need to check certain prices at betfair.com couple times per day. The website scraping serves best for this purpose. The only extra thing I need is to be logged in the website because of no delay. Because I have an account that is no longer used, security is not an issue, it just has to work.
I use the following options for the cURL requests, but it doesn't work.

```
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://www.betfair.com/en/',
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR=>'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'cookie.txt',
CURLOPT_POST=>1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>'username=user&password=pass
```

Comment: And what is your question/problem? What error do you see?

Comment: Website scraping seems like an odd choice when they provide a [free and well defined API](http://bdp.betfair.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=33&Itemid=44)...

Comment: The username / password are sent to this URL `https://accountservices.betfair.com/account/login/LoginRequest.do`, you're sending a request to their home page...

Comment: @Erwin Moller I'm just not logged in

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert I'll give it a try

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert when I print out the result of curl_exec, I get "1", it should mean success, right?

Comment: @user965748 It means that CURL has successfully retrieved a page. It doesn't say anything about the login status.

Comment: I see, it'll be trial and error now